# Dynamiccaly accessing array inside objects inside arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

First of all, i am relatively new to javascript so go easy on me :)

Here is my problem. I need to be able to dynamically navigate a multidimensionnal array that look like such :

```
Categories:[
     {id:cat1,
      name:cat1,
      childrens:[
           {id:cat1-subcat1,
            name:cat1-subcat1,
            childrens:[
                {id:cat1-subcat1-subcat1,
                 name:cat1-subcat1-subcat1,
                 childrens:[
etc...
```

The idea is as follow : the client can create categories and nest subcategories under them but also put sub categories inside subcategories.

So i can add a subcategorie to a categorie by doing :

```
categories[position].children.push(newcat)
```

Now my problem is how to do the same with a sub categorie.

```
categories[position].children[x].children.push(newcat)
```

getting the x value and storing it in the new created categorie could be possible and i guess i could work my way around 1 layer of subcatgories but the idea is that it is supposed to be able to create as many nested sub categories as necessaries. so it could look like :

```
categories[position].children[x].children[y].children[z].children.push(newcat)
```

So i need a dynamic way to access those places. not sur how to do it.

Can i access those nested object via their id ? like with map in a regular array.

How would i access cat1-subcat1-subcat1 with only knowing the id for exemple ???

I hope it make sens, i am availbale of course for more explanations

Thanks, Esteban

Comment: Please give your complete input. and expected output

Comment: well... the input is what i am trying to find and the output would be a way to access nested arrays.

I want a properties stored in each categorie, can call it path,
the you could do something like categories.slice(path.1)

I can dynamiccaly create a string that end up being "[position].children[x].children[y].children[z]" but it is useless because i cannot really use it

Comment: You may need a recursive solution, for each object, check if it contains a childrens key, and if so iterate it again, else do 'x' thing.

Answer (score 0):

So i have been trying to work on that piece of code.

To break down a simple array into a multidimensionnal one.
Each categorie store a level and parentid value.

Here is the code i am trying to work on,
Hope it makes sens to you guys. Again sorry for my poor javascript skill, that code very likely can be optimized.
Right now i would just like it to work :)

```
buildTreeview2(){
        var catdb = this.$catdb
        var lvl=0
        var temparray=[]
        var temparray2=[]
        var tempactif=1
        //var init = true
        var j
        var u 
        var i
        //console.log({catdb})
        // count how many lvls max
        for(i=0;i<catdb.length;i++){
          if (catdb[i].level>lvl){lvl=catdb[i].level}
        }

        if(lvl==0){
          this.categories=this.$catdb
        }
        else{
          for(u=lvl;u>=0;u--){
            //console.log(u)
            //put the items with the current lvl in an array
            for(i=0;i<catdb.length;i++){
              //console.log(catdb[i].level)
              if(tempactif==1){
                if(catdb[i].level==lvl){
                  temparray.push(catdb[i])
                }
              }else{
                if(catdb[i].level==lvl){
                  temparray2.push(catdb[i])
                }
              }
            }
            //check if first round with init value
            // if(init==true){
            //   tempactif=2
            //   init=false
            //   continue}
            // else{
                // add item from supperior lvl array to lower one
                if(tempactif==1){
                  for(i=0;i<temparray.length;i++){ 
                    for(j=0;j<temparray2.length;j++){ 
                      if(temparray[i].id==temparray2[j].parentid){
                        temparray[i].children.push(temparray2[j])
                      }
                    }
                  }

                }else{
                  for(i=0;i<temparray2.length;i++){ 
                    console.log(temparray2[i])
                    for(j=0;j<temparray.length;j++){ 
                      console.log(temparray[j])
                      if(temparray2[i].id==temparray[j].parentid){
                        
                        temparray2[i].children.push(temparray[j])
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
        //Switch tampactif value and clean temp array
         if(tempactif==1){
           //console.log(temparray)
            temparray2=[]
            tempactif=2
          }else{
           // console.log(temparray2)
            temparray=[]
            tempactif=1
          }

           // }//en of else
            
          }//end of lvl loop
          console.log('count')
          if(tempactif==1){
                this.categories=temparray2
              }else{
                this.categories=temparray
              }
        }
      },
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a way arround, so here it is if anyone has the same issue :

```
buildTreeview3(){
        var catdb=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$catdb))
        var lvl = 0
        var tempcat={}
        var u
        var i
        var parentid

        // count how many lvls max
        for(i=0;i<catdb.length;i++){
          if (catdb[i].level>lvl){lvl=catdb[i].level}
        }
        console.log('lvl : ',lvl)

        // if only base lvl, no need to build treeview
        if(lvl==0){
          this.categories=this.$catdb
        }
        else{
            for(u=lvl;u>0;u--){
              //for each lvl starting from highest, go through the temp database catdb
              for(i=0;i<catdb.length;i++){
                if(catdb[i].level==u){
                  //When found a categorie from current lvl, found the position of its parent and add it to its child
                  parentid = catdb[i].parentid
                  let parentpos = catdb.map(function (e) {
                      return e.id;
                    }).indexOf(parentid);
                    tempcat=catdb[parentpos]
                    tempcat.children.push(catdb[i])
                    
                     //remove the cat that has been added to childs from the temp db
                     //replace the parent by the parent with child
                      catdb.splice(i,1)
                      catdb.splice(parentpos,1,tempcat)
                      i=0
                }
              }
            }

        }//end of all (else if not just base lvl)
      this.categories=catdb

      },
```